# How can I run qmake tool on target with yocto?

Tags: linux, qt, yocto, qmake, petalinux

My team is using Petalinux 18.02 which uses Yocto ver.rocko and meta-qt5.

I added `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target "` in local.conf but it did not integrate qmake to target image. Then I modified local.conf one more time and added `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " qtbase-tools "` and it did that! So I finally integrated qmake tool on target system.

However, it does not work well...

Its configuration looks invalid and it can't find features, test functions.
I'll add a detail below.

```sh
# Environment variables
export QTDIR="/usr/bin/qt5"; 
export QTINC="/usr/include/qt5"; 
export QTLIB="/usr/lib/qt5"; 
export QMAKESPEC="/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/linux-oe-g++"; 
export QMAKEFEATURES="/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/features"; 
export PATH="${QTDIR}:${PATH}"
```

```sh
root@petalinux18.02:~# /usr/bin/qt5/qmake -query
QT_SYSROOT:/scratch/petalinux-yocto/yocto_downloads_2018.2_zynqmp-generic/build_zynqmp-generic/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinx-linuxt
QT_INSTALL_PREFIX:/scratch/petalinux-yocto/yocto_downloads_2018.2_zynqmp-generic/build_zynqmp-generic/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinr
QT_INSTALL_PREFIX/raw:/usr
QT_INSTALL_ARCHDATA:/scratch/petalinux-yocto/yocto_downloads_2018.2_zynqmp-generic/build_zynqmp-generic/tmp/work/aarch64-xil5
QT_INSTALL_ARCHDATA/raw:/usr/lib/qt5
QT_INSTALL_DATA:/scratch/petalinux-yocto/yocto_downloads_2018.2_zynqmp-generic/build_zynqmp-generic/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinx-5
QT_INSTALL_DATA/raw:/usr/share/qt5
QT_INSTALL_DOCS:/scratch/petalinux-yocto/yocto_downloads_2018.2_zynqmp-generic/build_zynqmp-generic/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinx-5
QT_INSTALL_DOCS/raw:/usr/share/doc/qt5
QT_INSTALL_HEADERS:/scratch/petalinux-yocto/yocto_downloads_2018.2_zynqmp-generic/build_zynqmp-generic/tmp/work/aarch64-xili5
QT_INSTALL_HEADERS/raw:/usr/include/qt5
QT_INSTALL_LIBS:/scratch/petalinux-yocto/yocto_downloads_2018.2_zynqmp-generic/build_zynqmp-generic/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinx-b
QT_INSTALL_LIBS/raw:/usr/lib
QT_INSTALL_LIBEXECS:/scratch/petalinux-yocto/yocto_downloads_2018.2_zynqmp-generic/build_zynqmp-generic/tmp/work/aarch64-xilc
QT_INSTALL_LIBEXECS/raw:/usr/lib/qt5/libexec
QT_INSTALL_BINS:/scratch/petalinux-yocto/yocto_downloads_2018.2_zynqmp-generic/build_zynqmp-generic/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinx-5
QT_INSTALL_BINS/raw:/usr/bin/qt5
QT_INSTALL_TESTS:/scratch/petalinux-yocto/yocto_downloads_2018.2_zynqmp-generic/build_zynqmp-generic/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinxs
QT_INSTALL_TESTS/raw:/usr/share/qt5/tests
QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS:/scratch/petalinux-yocto/yocto_downloads_2018.2_zynqmp-generic/build_zynqmp-generic/tmp/work/aarch64-xilis
QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS/raw:/usr/lib/qt5/plugins
QT_INSTALL_IMPORTS:/scratch/petalinux-yocto/yocto_downloads_2018.2_zynqmp-generic/build_zynqmp-generic/tmp/work/aarch64-xilis
QT_INSTALL_IMPORTS/raw:/usr/lib/qt5/imports
QT_INSTALL_QML:/scratch/petalinux-yocto/yocto_downloads_2018.2_zynqmp-generic/build_zynqmp-generic/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinx-ll
QT_INSTALL_QML/raw:/usr/lib/qt5/qml
QT_INSTALL_TRANSLATIONS:/scratch/petalinux-yocto/yocto_downloads_2018.2_zynqmp-generic/build_zynqmp-generic/tmp/work/aarch64s
QT_INSTALL_TRANSLATIONS/raw:/usr/share/qt5/translations
QT_INSTALL_CONFIGURATION:/scratch/petalinux-yocto/yocto_downloads_2018.2_zynqmp-generic/build_zynqmp-generic/tmp/work/aarch65
QT_INSTALL_CONFIGURATION/raw:/etc/qt5
QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES:/scratch/petalinux-yocto/yocto_downloads_2018.2_zynqmp-generic/build_zynqmp-generic/tmp/work/aarch64-xils
QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES/raw:/usr/share/qt5/examples
QT_INSTALL_DEMOS:/scratch/petalinux-yocto/yocto_downloads_2018.2_zynqmp-generic/build_zynqmp-generic/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinxs
QT_INSTALL_DEMOS/raw:/usr/share/qt5/examples
QT_HOST_PREFIX:/scratch/petalinux-yocto/yocto_downloads_2018.2_zynqmp-generic/build_zynqmp-generic/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinx-le
QT_HOST_DATA:/scratch/petalinux-yocto/yocto_downloads_2018.2_zynqmp-generic/build_zynqmp-generic/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinx-lin5
QT_HOST_BINS:/usr/bin/qt5
QT_HOST_LIBS:/scratch/petalinux-yocto/yocto_downloads_2018.2_zynqmp-generic/build_zynqmp-generic/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinx-linb
QMAKE_SPEC:linux-oe-g++
QMAKE_XSPEC:linux-oe-g++
QMAKE_VERSION:3.1
QT_VERSION:5.9.4
```

```
# test.pro

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = test_qmake
DEPENDPATH += .
INCLUDEPATH += .
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/qt5

# Input
HEADERS += test_qmake.hpp
SOURCES += test_qmake.cpp
```

```sh
root@petalinux18.02:~# ls
test.pro
root@petalinux18.02:~# /usr/bin/qt5/qmake 
/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/features/resolve_config.prf:25: 'addExclusiveBuilds' is not a recognized test function.
/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/features/resolve_config.prf:37: 'addExclusiveBuilds' is not a recognized test function.
Project ERROR: Could not find feature force_asserts.
```

I know running qmake on target not host is not normal. But our client wants it then I have to do it.

I have been searching a solution in google but I found out nothing...

Is there anyone else has a solution?